# Freeness of $I/I^2$ implies that of $\dfrac{I}{I^2+xR}$ over $R/I$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, local-rings

Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian local and $I$ be an ideal of $R$ such that $\sqrt{I}=\mathfrak m$. Let $x\in I\setminus I \mathfrak m$ be such that $x$ is a non-zerodivisor on $R$. If $I/I^2$ is $R/I$-free, then is $\dfrac{I}{I^2+xR}$ also $R/I$-free?

(Here note that $\dfrac{I}{I^2+xR}$ is square of the image of the ideal $I$ in $R/xR$).

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: let $k$ be a field, $A=k[[t]], B=k[[t^3, t^7, t^8]], \mathfrak{m}=t^3B+t^7B+t^8B, I= t^6A\subset B, x=t^{11}.$

$(B,\mathfrak{m})$ is a noetherian local ring and $\sqrt{I}=\mathfrak{m}$ in $B$. $\bar{B}:=B/I\simeq k\oplus kt^3$ and $I/I^2=\bar{B}t^6\oplus \bar{B}t^7\oplus \bar{B}t^8$.

On the other hand, $I/I^2+xB\simeq kt^6\oplus \dots \oplus kt^{10}$ as $k$-vector spaces, so that $I/I^2+xB$ has odd length. However, any finite free $B/I$-module must have even length.

Comment: Why is having a zero-divisor a problem? $B/I$ is an Artinian local ring, so of course every element of $\mathfrak m/I$ will be a zero-divisor on any $B/I$-module ...

Comment: If it is not a faithful $B/I$-module, that would be a contradiction... do you have not faithful over $B/I$ in your example?

Comment: I’m sorry but I was somehow confused.. the corrected argument should show that I/I^2+xB is not free.

Comment: In your example, if $I/I^2+xB$ Indeed is a $k$-vector space, then here's another argument without even counting length: If $I/I^2+xB$ is a $k$-vector space,  then it is annihilated by $\mathfrak m$, so if it were also a free $B/I$-module, then $I=\mathfrak m$, contradicting your choice of $I$ ...

Comment: I will go through your choices of $B$, $I$ and $x$ carefully to see if $I/I^2+xB$ is a $k$-vector space, or equivalently, if $\mathfrak m I \subseteq I^2+xB$ or not ...

Comment: I/I^2+xB is not and does not have to be annihilated by $\mathfrak{m}$. We are seeing it as k-module by restricting its B-module structure i.e. we are considering $k \to B \to \mathrm{End}(I/I^2+xB)$. We are not seeing it as $B/\mathfrak{m}=k$-module here.